# Fastify route not working with specific url

Tags: javascript, node.js, fastify

I have this router in my code

```
fastify.get('/:link', (req, reply) => {
    req.params.url = req.host+req.url;
    reply.view("template.ejs",req.params);

});
```

I am trying to catch URLs and handle them in the template. The URLs are all `encodeURIComponent` escaped.  for some reason, some URLs would return a 404 not found and I am not sure why.
This is the link that worked.

http://127.0.0.1:3000/https%3A%2F%2Fupload.wikimedia.org%2Fwikipedia%2Fcommons%2Fe%2Fee%2FChain_link_icon.png

and this is the one that didn't work.

http://127.0.0.1:3000/https%3A%2F%2Fs7386.pcdn.co%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2016%2F07%2Fadd-on-direct-link-tracking-771x386.png

the error is

```
{
"message": "Route GET:/https%3A%2F%2Fs7386.pcdn.co%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2016%2F07%2Fadd-on-direct-link-tracking-771x386.png not found",
"error": "Not Found",
"statusCode": 404
}
```

I am using windows 10 with node v12.8.0 and fastify 2.8.0

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason was that the URL was more than 100 characters which is the maximum for some reason.

it can be changed by using the [maxparamlength](https://github.com/fastify/fastify/blob/main/docs/Reference/Server.md#maxparamlength). I also asked [here](https://github.com/fastify/help/issues/103) and hopefully, the error will be changed in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like below to extend the max length for the path parameter in fastify:

```
import * as fastify from 'fastify';

fastify.default({
  maxParamLength: 1000,
});
```